# Rails model to model relation in different context

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, orm, model

I have records with author and moderator. So I have two models Record and User:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :author_id, :moderator_id
end
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :uid

  validates :uid, :presence => true
  validates :name, :presence => true

  has_many :documents
end
```

Can anyone suggest a good solution for establishing a relation between these models, so that one record can have only one author and only one moderator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by referencing the model `User` twice in the `Record` model.

Record creation table should contain two lines something like this :

```
  t.references :author
  t.references :moderator
```

Record model should look like

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :author_id, :moderator_id

  validates :author_id, moderator_id, :uniqueness => true  # To have unique author and moderator for each record

  belongs_to :author, class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :moderator, class_name => 'User'
end
```